# Remove multple occurance of a word with another from python list

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a list in a particular format as follows:

```py
my_list =  ['apple', 'apple', 'boy', 'cat', 'cat', 'apple', 'apple', 
             'apple', 'boy', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog'].
```

And my expected output is

```py
res = ['apple', 'boy', 'cat', 'apple',  'boy', 'cat',  'dog']
```

The consecutive occurrence of the same word should be replaced with the word only once irrespective of whether the word occurred as another sequence earlier.

The following code when I used gives the following output.

```
test_list = ['apple', 'apple', 'boy', 'cat', 'cat', 'apple', 'apple', 
         'apple', 'boy', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog'] 
res = []
[res.append(x) for x in test_list if x not in res] 
print ("The list after removing duplicates : " + str(res))
```

output:
['apple', 'boy', 'cat', 'dog'] - which gave only distinct words.
How will I proceed from here to get what I actually require. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate question.

Comment: Thank you for finding the duplicate. The SO search never seems to work very well for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `itertools.groupby`

```py
from itertools import groupby

[key for key, _ in groupby(my_list)]
```

```
['apple', 'boy', 'cat', 'apple', 'boy', 'cat', 'dog']
```

Comment: I simplified your code - the first element of the returned tuples, which you initially ignored, is already exactly what you want (so there's no need to parse the second element).

Answer (score 0):

Use `set()`, which ignores duplicate values.

```
test_list = ['apple', 'apple', 'boy', 'cat', 'cat', 'apple', 'apple', 
         'apple', 'boy', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog'] 
         
t = set(test_list)
```

**Ouput :**

```
{'apple', 'boy', 'cat', 'dog'}
```

If needed, you can convert the `set` back into a `list` by

```
list(t)
```

**Output :**

```
['dog', 'boy', 'apple', 'cat']
```

Comment: Please read OPs question. This is not what they are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
my_list =  ['apple', 'apple', 'boy', 'cat', 'cat', 'apple', 'apple', 
             'apple', 'boy', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog'] + [""]
res = [my_list[i] for i in range(len(my_list) -1) if my_list[i+1] != my_list[i]] 
print(res)
```